# PCIe cards interfere with each others function

Tags: audio, pci-e

Hello Good People of the Internet!

First time asking...

I have a modern PC running Fedora 24 with a real-time patch (CCRMA audio tools) with an ASUS Essence STX II sterio sound card installed on PCIe. With it we run a playback/capture application. Also, we need to integrate CAN and BLE into the system and have a PCIe-card for each of these functions. The CAN PCIe card is from PEAK and the BLE card is an Intel 8260 M2 card that HP have put on a PCIe card (AFAIK).

With only the audio card installed it works fine (using ALSA as API). When the CAN and BLE is installed the following is observed:

- Playback works as before.
- One capture channel only returns zero (0) or minus one (-1) in all samples.
- The other capture channel returns values in the range -2..2 and when applying our application signal processing low quality, but detectable, expected results are presented.
- The ALSA API report no problems in setup  and configuration.
- CAN and BLE functions as expected.

Without any deeper PCIe experience I suspect that CAN and/or BLE PCIe cards jumble the mapping of the sound card functions.

Can someone:
 - Tell me if my hunch is in the ballpark?
 - Inform me on where I might go for information on how to rectify the problem?
 - ...or, share a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is meant to ask and answer questions about programming problems. Hardware-related questions, or UNIX/Linux-related questions are to be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Pierre-Loup Thank you! I try my question there.

Comment: A soulution to this can be found at [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419399/pcie-cards-interfere-with-each-others-function/420899#420899).